# What is a good practice for right margin control?

Tags: xetex, margins

I'm generally typesetting prose books, so I get a lot of right margins ;)

What I currently do is check visually if the right margins are so overflown that it looks bad. I find this tiresome and error prone, so I'm looking for a smarter approach.

Below is an MWE that shows the issue. I kept in the packages that I think could be relevant.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\raggedbottom
%\overfullrule=5pt % draft mode
\begin{document}
This is where we put some random nonsense to see how the margins look. And now a long word: pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis. Another one: pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism. Random long words to get a bad word break: floccinaucinihilipilification, antidisestablishmentarianism, supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `xelatex`, this will give us this output:

[image: Margins]

It looks okay, right? But looks what happens when we uncomment the line `\overfullrule=5pt`:

[image: Margins]

Ouch! The margin has not been respected. And sure enough, we find this in `mwe.log`:

```
Overfull \hbox (0.384pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--11
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 floccinaucinihilipilification, antidisestablishmentarianism, sup
er-|
```

Now I have to decide if 0.384pt is enough that I should rephrase the text, or see if I could have the split elsewhere. I hope there is a more effective way of working? I think that adding a line that forbids any margin breaks might be a good idea?

Comment: \sloppy is better than \fussy for the right margin, and is SOP for narrow columns.  It does, however, waste space with gaps between words.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that LaTeX has problem with hyphenation of your text.

If the hyphenation algorithm does not find the correct hyphenation points (in your artificial long words), you can remedy the situation by using the following commands to tell TeX about the exception. For example with adding:

```
\hyphenation{pseudo-pseudo-hy-po-pa-rathy-roi-dism pneumo-no-ultra-micro-scopics-i-li-co-vol-ca-no-co-nio-sis}
```

in preamble (since I'm not native speaker, the hyphens may be misplaced).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\hyphenation{FORTRAN Hy-phen-a-tion}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hyphenation{pseudo-pseudo-hy-po-pa-rathy-roi-dism pneumo-no-ultra-micro-scopics-i-li-co-vol-ca-no-co-nio-sis}
\overfullrule=5pt % draft mode

\begin{document}
This is where we put some random nonsense to see how the margins look. And now a long word: pneumonoultramicro\-scopicsilicovolcanoconiosis. Another one: pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism. Random long words to get a bad word break: floccinaucinihilipilification, antidisestablishmentarianism, supercalifragilisticexpialidocious.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the issue I have is that I have to manually decide whether the (unavoidable?) overflows are significant enough that I should do something about them. I find that these overflows always happen.

PS: The words are real, if weird ;-)